# Creating a list of keys and value[0] from a dict after sorting

Tags: list, dictionary

I'm trying to filter some information inside a dict, using lists of values for each key, and in case there is more than 1 value, we choose the better one, is this case, if the [1][3] position is higher its sorted accordingly.

```
for key, value in dic.items():
    if len(value) < 1:
        newList.append(TranslatorToTask('NOTAssigned', key))
    if len(value) == 1:
        newList.append(TranslatorToTask(value[0], key))
    if len(value) > 1:
        for v in dic.values():
            v.sort(key=lambda t: float(t[1][3]), reverse = True)
            newList.append(TranslatorToTask(value[0], key))
```

Still, when i print the newList it comes out like this:

All work except the else statement that besides not returning the first position translator, also runs 3 more times.

Info about the expected result: and used function:

```
def TranslatorToTask(translator, task):

    newList = [translator, task]
    return newList
```

And while im asking, is it possible to additional values to sorted in case the ones compared are equal?

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this part

```
for v in dic.values():
    v.sort(key=lambda t: float(t[1][3]), reverse = True)
```

which I give you in the your other question is for sorting each element in whole dictionary, to use locally as you want to use it here, you only need the sort part

```
for key, value in dic.items():
    if len(value) < 1:
        newList.append(TranslatorToTask('NOTAssigned', key))
    if len(value) == 1:
        newList.append(TranslatorToTask(value[0], key))
    if len(value) > 1:
        value.sort(key=lambda t: float(t[1][3]), reverse = True) #<-- only the sort
        newList.append(TranslatorToTask(value[0], key))
```

or as you only want the element with the biggest value of `t[1][3]`, you can use [max](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) (or [min](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) for the other extreme) function which also accept a key function, like this

```
max( value, key=lambda t: float( t[1][3] )
```

resulting in this

```
for key, value in dic.items():
    if len(value) < 1:
        newList.append(TranslatorToTask('NOTAssigned', key))
    if len(value) == 1:
        newList.append(TranslatorToTask(value[0], key))
    if len(value) > 1:
        newList.append( TranslatorToTask( max( value, key=lambda t: float(t[1][3])), key) )
```

it also accept a default value in case the list you give to it is empty, that is value that you get from it, which it could reduce that piece of code to this:

```
for key, value in dic.items():
    newList.append( TranslatorToTask( max( value, key=lambda t: float(t[1][3]), default='NOTAssigned'), key ) )
```

(because the max of empty list is default, the max from a list with only 1 element is that element, and the max from a list with 2 or more, is well, the maximum among them according to the key function)

---

by the way the error was here

```
for key, value in dic.items():
    ...
    if len(value) > 1:
        for v in dic.values():
            v.sort(key=lambda t: float(t[1][3]), reverse = True)
            newList.append(TranslatorToTask(value[0], key))  #<---here
```

this append is executed as many times as there are keys in the dictionary

Also is that is all that the `TranslatorToTask` function would do, is more shorter to just write that directly instead of making a function for just that

Comment: Again, thanks alot for the reply, there is an issue though, i can't use functions like max, min, zip, etc, the only inbuilt function in allowed to use is sorted and sort.. :/ also, any ideia if inside a sorted function i can use multiple values in case they are equal?

Comment: Also, append doesnt allow me to use multiple values, how would you advise to make it? And can i get only the first value (the name of the person) instead of all the info in the last part?

Comment: in that case your key function need to build a tuple with the elements you want to use to order by its importance, like `key=lambda t: (val1, val1, val3,...)` and each valn is something you extract from `t` of course...

Comment: with the append part, well is simple, you append one list with the desired values to it like `newList.append( [X, Y] ) ` (for any X and Y). You can append any arbitrary object, and a list is just one object, that just so happens to contains an arbitrary number of others objects

Comment: Thanks! Now only need to figure out how to build this sorted part and make it not run 100 times :)

Comment: mmm, maybe I'm reading too much into it, but that sound like my previous padawan, that have the answer right in from of him jet fail to see it...

Comment: I'm so sorry, i just got carried away and didn't see the first part! Thanks alot sir, if you're ever in Portugal i'll buy you a beer!

Comment: Ok, but too bad I live in the other side of the Atlantic in the tropic ;)